# Reading files: File name not working

Tags: java, file-io

In the following the code I keep getting the error "(No such file or directory)"

```
public void readFile() throws IOException {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("map1.txt"));

    while(true) {
        String line = reader.readLine();
        System.out.println(line);
        if(line == null) {
            reader.close();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I get this same error when I try to read images / anything really. But in the examples I've seen of how to use file readers they all just put in the name of the files and nothing else. In this case the map is in a separate folder in the src file called Maps. I've tried various specifications of "/Maps/map1.txt" but nothing seems to work. **How do I get this file to read?**

(I'm on a mac as well. I don't know if that changes things.)

**Update**

Seems like it is netBeans' fault. It only looks the project folder. I think I'll start another topic asking how to remedy this later. Thank you for all the help everyone.

Comment: add a 
 `System.out.println ("Current directory's canonical path: " 
  + new File (".").getCanonicalPath()); ` to print the current directory, before the read to see if the path is correct

Comment: This is printing the exact location of the file now. But if I try to plug that in to the load the file I still get the error. Bizarre...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In this case the map is in a separate folder in the src file called Maps.

I assume you have a folder named `src` which has  your java files; in this same folder there is a folder named `Maps` which has `map1.txt`.

Now,

> reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("map1.txt"));

Is going to to try to open the file map1.txt in the **current directory**. Which directory this is depends on the IDE you use; but you should be able to change it.

If you change it to the folder which has the file it should work.

Comment: I've tried moving the map.txt into the same folder as the code but seeing no change. Is that what you meant by same directory?

Answer (score 2):

`/Maps/map1.txt` is an absolute path, starting at the top directory. Try `./Maps/map1.txt`, as long as you are running the java app from the directory above Maps.

Comment: Maps is a separate package in the source folder with the package containing the .java with this method. '/Maps/map1.txt' doesn't make any change.

Answer (score 1):

I extracted some pieces of my program that may be helpful:

```
FileInputStream configFile = new FileInputStream("javalogging.properties");
```

In the case above, the file is on the same level of the *src* folder (which means, out of the source folder)

```
    FileInputStream configFile = (FileInputStream)
              MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/javalogging.properties");
```

In the case above, sure you are going to replace `MyClass` by your class name, and put the file inside the source folder (useful if you're planning to deploy your application in a way the properties is inside the jar file)

Using the bufferedReader, I used the entire path, as you can see below:

```
File file = new File(filePath+fileName);
BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader (new FileReader(file.getAbsoluteFile()));
```